# Django query ManyToMany for tagged items

Tags: python, django

I've got a item inventory that each inventory item is tagged with multiple tags. What I've got is an API that takes a query parameter with multiple comma separated query items and returns a list of all items that match *all* of the tags.

The following code is working, however this isn't really using the ManyToMany attributes in the Django models and I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Schema ---

```
class InventoryTag(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('key', 'value')

    key   = models.CharField(max_length=240, db_index=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=240, db_index=True)

class InventoryItem(models.Model):
    instance_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(InventoryTag, through='InventoryItemTag', through_fields=('item', 'tag'))

    def as_json(self):
        return serializers.serialize('json', [self])[0]

class InventoryItemTag(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('item', 'tag')

    item = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem, db_index=True, related_name='invitem')
    tag  = models.ForeignKey(InventoryTag, db_index=True, related_name='invtag')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Get Function --

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '').strip()
    start = int(request.GET.get('start', 0))
    count = int(request.GET.get('count', 50))

    query_items = [q.strip() for q in query.split(',') if q.strip()]

    items = InventoryItem.objects
    if query_items:
        for q in query_items:
            tags = InventoryTag.objects
            q = q.lstrip(':')
            if ':' in q:
                (k, v) = q.split(':', 1)
                tags = tags.filter(Q(key = k) & Q(value__startswith = v))
            else:
                tags = tags.filter(value__startswith = q)

            tags_pks = InventoryItemTag.objects.filter(Q(tag__in = tags.values_list('id')))
            items = items.filter(pk__in=tags_pks.values_list('item_id'))

    items = items.all()
```

How this is used:

- InventoryItem -- For practical purpose this is an AWS instance with an instance_id
- InventoryTag -- Other attributes of that instance (e.g. Name) or IP address. This is unique for any key/value pair of the tag.

You might have a set of instances like:

```
Item(id=1) -- tags:  name=dev.test zone=us-east-1a
Item(id=2) -- tags:  name=dev.vpc  zone=us-east-1a
Item(id=3) -- tags:  name=dev.cron zone=us-east-1a
Item(id=4) -- tags:  name=dev.test zone=us-east-1c
Item(id=5) -- tags:  name=dev.test zone=us-west-2a
```

So the goal is that you should be able to do a search where you ask for all name=dev.test and zone=us-east-1a machines and get item #1 and #4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are, more or less, manually performing in Python what can be achieved in SQL using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q). Basically, you can chain Q objects to create an SQL query on the `InventoryItems` with one `WHERE` clause for each part of your HTTP query.

Also note that, on queryset operations that will be converted to a `WHERE` clause (like `get`, `filter`...) as well as `Q` objects, the keywords arguments are `AND`ed together. So there is no need in doing `tags.filter(Q(key = k) & Q(value__startswith = v))` since `tags.filter(key=k, value__startswith=v)` performs the same query and is more readable.

Building the tags research query should already include the lookup that span relationship and can be something like:

```
relevant_tags = Q()  # Fallback, if the query is empty will select everything
for tag_searched in query_items:
    tag_searched = tag_searched.lstrip(':')
    try:
        tag_name, tag_value = tag_searched.split(':', 1)
    except ValueError:
        # tag_searched did not contain any :
        query = Q(tags__value__startswith=tag_searched)
    else:
        query = Q(tags__key=tag_name, tags__value__startswith=tag_value)

    relevant_tags = relevant_tags & query
```

And from there, we can retrieve objects we want in a single query:

```
items = InventoryItems.objects.filter(relevant_tags)
```

A few things to note:

- `if iterable` just before `for element in iterable` is pointless as the for loop will be a no-op anyway if the iterable is empty;
- you can use [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp) rather than [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-lbyl), especially if you expect one path to happen more frequently than the other. I made a wild guess that the user will use the `name:value` syntax of the query more often than the simple `value` one. It is also to show an alternate syntax.
- you can clean your query better in the list-comprehension to avoid an extra `lstrip` in the computation. Or you can avoid the list-comp and perform the whole cleanup in the for loop:

  ```
  for tag_searched in query.split(','):
      tag_searched = tag_searched.strip().lstrip(':')
      if not tag_searched:
          continue
      ...
  ```
- you never use `start` or `count`, you should remove them.

Comment: If I read this code this affects an OR on the Tags rather than an AND on the tag items.  So a query of "us-west-1a" "dev.test" would return 5 items (from the example) rather than 2.

Now I could be reading the code wrong, but lacking any AND to cause an intersection on the result sets I'm concerned.

Comment: @koblas Let's base our reflexion on tag ids rather than values and names. Let's say that "dev.test" is 1 and "us-west-1a" is 3. So `InventoryTag.objects.filter(relevant_tags)` would roughtly translate to `SELECT * FROM django_inventory_tag WHERE id=1 OR id=3`, yielding the two tags we are interested in. We then filter `InventoryItemTag` and/or `InventoryItems` for elements that contains both ids. The AND you are looking for is hiden in `tags.values_list('id')`.

Comment: As long as there is a OR on the InventoryTag you're not getting the correct result.  I have tested it.  You get all items that have "us-west-1" OR "dev.test" you do not get the AND intersection of the two sets of inventory items that have both tags.

Comment: @koblas Ok, my bad, even if the `tags.values_list('id')` is an `AND`, the `tag__in` or `tags__id__in` is still a `OR`. Will rewrite the answer shortly

Comment: @koblas Done, it should be better now